# Why do I get the error "file format not recognized; treating as linker script" when compiling my Unix copy program?

Tags: c, unix, gcc

I am new to Unix and I want to make a copy program that uses CL for compiling it. I get: "file format not recognized; treating as linker script".

This is my code for copying from source file to destination

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fsource, *fdestination;

    printf("enter the name of source file:\n");
    char sourceName[20], destinationName[20];
    strcpy(sourceName, argv[1]);
    strcpy(destinationName, argv[2]);
    
    
    fsource = fopen(sourceName, "r");
    if (fsource == NULL)
        printf("Nije uspjelo otvaranje file-a za citanje\n");
    else
        printf("Uspjesno ste otvorili file za citanje!\n");
    fdestination = fopen(destinationName, "w");
    if (fdestination == NULL)
        printf("Nije uspjelo otvaranje file-a za pisanje\n");
    else
        printf("Uspjesno ste otvorili file za pisanje!\n");

    char pen = fgetc(fsource);
    while (pen != EOF)
    {
        fputc(pen, fdestination);
        pen = fgetc(fsource);
    }
        

    fclose(fsource);
    fclose(fdestination);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile it from vm using "`gcc 2.c source.txt destination.txt`" command. I've created two files in the same directory.

Comment: What are `source.txt` and `destination.txt`?

Comment: Compiling and running a program need to be separate steps on separate lines.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't copy the filename strings. Either use `argv[1]` directly, or have `sourceName` be a pointer pointing to the same string as `argv[1]`. Like this: `char *sourceName=argv[1]`;  Same goes for `argv[2]` and `destinationName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compile the program (that means, making an executable application out of the code) and run it at the same time. You need to compile your application first using:

`gcc 2.c -o programname`

and then execute it via

`./programname source.txt destination.txt`

Comment: I just supplied a similar answer because of time overlap. Sorry. Your answer is equally valid.

Answer (score 1):

You supplied the command line arguments which are intended for your program to the gcc compiler, instead. This is wrong. First compile your program using e.g. `gcc 2.c -o mycopy` and then invoke your program by `./mycopy source.txt destination.txt`.

```
$gcc 2.c -o mycopy 
$echo "test1234" > source.txt 
$cat source.txt
test1234
$./mycopy source.txt destination.txt
enter the name of source file:
Uspjesno ste otvorili file za citanje!
Uspjesno ste otvorili file za pisanje!
$ls
2.c  destination.txt  mycopy  source.txt
$cat destination.txt
test1234
```

Voila, seems your copy program produced the desired result!